# What fonts are available on Android?

Tags: android, fonts

I know that android has a [collection of fonts](http://www.ascenderfonts.com/store/search.aspx?q=Droid+) specifically designed by Ascender for Google, but what other fonts are available? I'm looking for a list like [this one](http://daringfireball.net/2007/07/iphone_fonts) or even better [this one.](http://daringfireball.net/misc/2007/07/iphone-osx-fonts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the Ascender collection is the full list of fonts that come installed with Android.  You can however include your own True Type fonts in your app (as long as your app isn't a Homescreen App Widget).

Comment: Have a look here for more information: http://www.droidfonts.com/

Comment: This ascender collection? http://www.monotype.com/libraries/ascender