# What fonts are installed by default on Android?

Tags: android, fonts

What fonts are installed by default on Android devices?

I know about the [Droid fonts](http://www.droidfonts.com/) and [Roboto](https://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html), but what about core web fonts like Arial, Times, or Verdana? Are they available? What other fonts are installed by default on Android devices?

(This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065818/what-fonts-are-available-on-android), but the accepted answer is outdated)

Comment: No these are not available by default. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are only three system wide fonts in Android;

> 1 normal (Droid Sans),
>
> 2 serif (Droid Serif),
>
> 3 monospace (Droid Sans Mono).

Applications can install fonts for themselves, but not for system-wide use.

For more you can see [List of fonts included with each device link](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/List_of_fonts_included_with_each_device)

and

Since the Ice Cream Sandwich release, `Roboto` has been the standard typeface on Android.

Since Froyo, `Noto` has been the standard typeface on Android for all languages not covered by Roboto. Noto is also the standard typeface for all languages on Chrome OS.

[Refer here](http://www.google.co.in/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-roboto-noto)

Comment: Wrong. You didn't mention the Roboto fonts family which is available starting from the Android 4.0.

Comment: please leave a  comment for the reason of  downvote

Comment: This is not default on android devices its depend upon what version you are using.

Comment: I have added that part to .. In my answer.

Comment: 90% of all Android devices are 4.0+ and I don't see anybody around me starting new project which supports something earlier than Ice Cream Sandvich, so if your `minSdkVersion` is greater or equal to 14 (and it should be, because it's time to drop support of earlier versions) it's safe to assume that Roboto is default font.

Comment: Its safe to assume thats why i have added that part thanks for correcting me . :-)

Comment: I downvoted because the top, highlighted thing in your answer is out of date information. You should edit it to put the most likely thing to be true in this day and age at the top of your answer.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on Android version.

In Lollipop **ROBOTO FONT FAMILY** is installed.

For more detail go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809944/default-font-set-on-android).