What fonts are bundled with Google Chrome on Android
I'm looking to build a set of web-safe fonts. Its easy to find information on fonts bundled with Apple/Windows OS - but not so much on Android.
The documentations states that Android comes with 3'ish fonts bundled - and then apps have their own fonts as needed.
I am unable to find a list of standard fonts for Google Chrome on Android (or any other browser on Android). Anyone know more about this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384114/what-fonts-are-installed-by-default-on-android

Not a complete answer, but some information on minimum font requirements is in the Compatibility Definition Document
